# AWS Step Function: Comparing Items in Different Arrays

Tags: aws-step-functions

I have a step function where I'm trying to check if one or all items in array 1 match any item in array 2 but I am coming up blank.

The JSON is as below:

```json
{
  "Data": {
    "Array1": [
      "X",
      "Y",
      "Z"
    ],
    "Array2": [
      "A",
      "B",
      "C"
    ]
  }
}
```

I have tried using `States.ArrayContains` as outlined in the AWS documentation but I think this compares the entire array as opposed to the individual items within against each other, code outlined below.

```json
"Pass": {
  "Type": "Pass",
  "End": true,
  "Parameters": {
    "contains.$": "States.ArrayContains($.Array2, $.Array1)"
  },
  "InputPath.$": "$.Data"
}
```

I also had the idea to separate the above code into `key,value` pairs in the array and then using the `Map` item but am a but confused as to how to set this up since there are two different arrays:

```json
{
  "Data": {
    "Array1": [
      {
        "item": "X"
      },
      {
        "item": "Y"
      },      
      {
        "item": "Z"
      }
    ],
    "Array2": [
      {
        "item": "A"
      },
      {
        "item": "B"
      },
      {      
        "item": "C"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea.  Iterate over the items in `Array1` with a [Map State](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-asl-use-map-state-inline.html) and look for overlaps with `States.ArrayContains`.

`Parameters` customizes the input to each iteration:  an `Item` and `Array2`.  The `ItemProcessor` is a Pass State that looks for the `Item` in `Array2` with the `States.ArrayContains` [intrinsic function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html#asl-intrsc-func-arrays).  Each Pass state returns something like `{"isInArray2" : false}`, which is output from the Map as an array.  The `ResultsSelector` summarizes the array output.  It looks for trues.  There is an overlap if any of the items is true.

```json
{
  "Comment": "Are there items in Array1 that are also in Array2?",
  "StartAt": "FindOverlaps",
  "States": {
    "FindOverlaps": {
      "Type": "Map",
      "InputPath": "$.Data",
      "Parameters": {
        "Item.$": "$$.Map.Item.Value",
        "Array2.$": "$.Array2"
      },
      "ItemProcessor": {
        "ProcessorConfig": {
          "Mode": "INLINE"
        },
        "StartAt": "FindRunning",
        "States": {
          "FindRunning": {
            "Type": "Pass",
            "Parameters": {
              "isInArray2.$": "States.ArrayContains($.Array2, $.Item)"
            },
            "End": true
          }
        }
      },
      "End": true,
      "ResultSelector": {
        "hasOverlaps.$": "States.ArrayContains($..isInArray2, true)"
      },
      "ResultPath": "$.findOverlaps",
      "ItemsPath": "$.Array1"
    }
  }
}
```

For the input in the OP, which has no overlap, the output would be:

```json
"findOverlaps": {
    "hasOverlaps": false
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved my issue. Could you explain what the `"Item.$": "$$.Map.Item.Value"` part does? I think this was the step holding me back and the AWS documentation isn't too clear on it's usage.

Comment: @rhynohorn Glad to help.  That bit uses the [context object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-contextobject.html#contextobject-map) to customize the payload each iteration receives.  By default, Map state iterations receive the array item as the input.  The (deprecated but valid) Parameters field (and the [ItemSelector](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-itemselector.html) field that replaces it) override the iterations' input.